# change webview content with button Next/Previous?

Tags: android, webview, reload

I have a `webView` with some content from *assets/1.html* and I want to create a `button` (Next Button) to change the content of my `webView` to *assets/2.html* and so on.

**how to do that ?**

**P.S.** I did it with an `Intent` and recreate my `Activity` but I think this is not a good solution, I want JUST the `webView` to reload not all `Activity` :)

this is my NextStory() function:

```
    public void nextStory(View view) {

    int iExtra = Integer.parseInt(extra) + 1;

    if(iExtra<=10) {
        String sExtra = Integer.toString(iExtra);
        webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/"+sExtra+".htm");

    } else {
        inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.toast,
                (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.toast_root));

        text = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.text);
        text.setText("لقد وصلت لنهاية الكتاب!");

        toast = new Toast(getApplicationContext());
        toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 0);
        toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.setView(layout);
        toast.show();
    }
}
```

this is my onCreate() function :

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_book);

    textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);

    Typeface face = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
            "fonts/arabicfont.otf");
    textView.setTypeface(face);

    webView = (WebView)this.findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);

    intent = getIntent();

    //this intent tag is for start reading position
    extra = intent.getExtras().getString("EXTRA");

    //this colorId is selected from previous Activity to change color acording to user's needs
    colorId = intent.getIntExtra("COLOR_EXTRA", colorId);

    Linear1 = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.Linear1);
    Relative1 = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.Relative1);
    Linear1.setBackgroundResource(colorId);
    Relative1.setBackgroundResource(colorId);

    if(extra.equals("0")) {
        webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/1.htm");
        textView.setText(textView.getText().toString()+ " > توطئة");

    } else if(extra.equals("1")) {
        webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/2.htm");
        textView.setText(textView.getText().toString()+ " > الكآبة الخرساء");

    } else if(extra.equals("2")) {
        webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/3.htm");
        textView.setText(textView.getText().toString()+ " > يد القضاء");

    } else if(extra.equals("3")) {
        webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/4.htm");
        textView.setText(textView.getText().toString()+ " > في باب الهيكل");

    } else if(extra.equals("4")) {
        webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/5.htm");
        textView.setText(textView.getText().toString()+ " > الشعلة البيضاء");

    } else if(extra.equals("5")) {
        webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/6.htm");
        textView.setText(textView.getText().toString()+ " > العاصفة");

    } else if(extra.equals("6")) {
        webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/7.htm");
        textView.setText(textView.getText().toString()+ " > بحيرة النار");

    } else if(extra.equals("7")) {
        webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/8.htm");
        textView.setText(textView.getText().toString()+ " > أمام عرش الموت");

    } else if(extra.equals("8")) {
        webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/9.htm");
        textView.setText(textView.getText().toString()+ " > عشتروت والمسيح");

    } else if(extra.equals("9")) {
        webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/10.htm");
        textView.setText(textView.getText().toString()+ " > التضحية");

    } else if(extra.equals("10")) {
        webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/11.htm");
        textView.setText(textView.getText().toString()+ " > المنقذ");
    }
}
```

Comment: bro just load or  set the second html file to the same webview it will work

Comment: you can add next button into you html1 file and can navigate to html2 using htlm functionality

Answer (score 0):

Create **Next** and **Previous** buttons in your activity and `just change the url of webview on button click.`

Comment: if you have tried doing this then post your code in your question

Comment: otherswise clear the cache of that webview. and load again

Answer (score 0):

Declare on top of your `Activity`:

```
private int currentWebPageIndex;
```

Then when you press next/prev you add/remove a value from index like

```
currentWebPageIndex++/currentWebPageIndex--
```

So you could have a method like

```
private void pressedButton(boolean next){
    if(next){
       currentWebPageIndex++;
    } else {
       currentWebPageIndex--;
    }

    // load url depending on currentWebPageIndex
}
```

Comment: my problem is in // load url depending on currentWebPageIndex 
i have no luck of immagination; my problem is technical ..

Comment: But you have succeeded to load the ulr once? So you know how to do that.

Comment: For instance, if currentWebpageIndex == 0, load url1, if == 1, load url2, and so on for all type of pages you want to load. feel me?